# How to register a ReverseRegistrar with ENSRegistry

Tags: ens

I want to build an ENS system on my chain and I'm deploying the contract by referring to https://github.com/ensdomains/ens-contracts.

I am facing a problem while deploying the contract.
In the process of deploying NameWrapper to build an ENS system, the constructor has the following logic.

```
// ens-contracts/wrapper/NameWrapper.sol
constructor(
        ENS _ens,
        IBaseRegistrar _registrar,
        IMetadataService _metadataService
    ) ReverseClaimer(_ens, msg.sender) {
        ...
    }

// ens-contracts/registrar/ReverseClaimer.sol
constructor(ENS ens, address claimant) {
        IReverseRegistrar reverseRegistrar = IReverseRegistrar(
            ens.owner(ADDR_REVERSE_NODE)
        );
        reverseRegistrar.claim(claimant);
    }
```

The constructor of ReverseClaimer calls the ReverseRegistrar via `IReverseRegistrar(ens.owner(ADDR_REVERSE_NODE))`, which in an initial system implementation would be `ens.owner(ADDR_REVERSE_NODE)) = address(0)`.
If so, the next statement, `reverseRegistrar.claim(claimant)`, is bound to fail.

To solve this problem, you need to register the deployed reverseRegistrar contract address as owner in ENSRegistry first, but ENSRegistry's setOwner function is implemented as below.

```
modifier authorised(bytes32 node) {
        address owner = records[node].owner;
        require(owner == msg.sender || operators[owner][msg.sender]);
        _;
    }

function setOwner(
        bytes32 node,
        address owner
    ) public virtual override authorised(node) {
        _setOwner(node, owner);
        emit Transfer(node, owner);
    }
```

After all, the modifier authorized() prevents us from registering ReverseRegistrar as owner (because the previous owner was address(0))
How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing arises from the fact that the `ReverseClaimer` contract tries to claim ownership of the reverse node (`ADDR_REVERSE_NODE`) without having it registered in the ENS registry first. This is indeed a challenge when dealing with the authorization checks in the `ENSRegistry`.

To address this problem, you can follow these steps:

1. **Pre-Deploy Reverse Registrar:**
   Deploy the `ReverseRegistrar` contract separately before deploying the `NameWrapper` contract. This way, you have its address available to register as the owner of the reverse node.
2. **Register Reverse Registrar as Owner:**
   After deploying the `ReverseRegistrar`, use the `setOwner` function of the `ENSRegistry` to register the `ReverseRegistrar` as the owner of the reverse node (`ADDR_REVERSE_NODE`). This involves calling the `setOwner` function, and since it's protected by the `authorized` modifier, you need to ensure that the calling address is authorized to set the owner.

Here's a general sequence of steps:

```
// Deploy ReverseRegistrar
IReverseRegistrar reverseRegistrar = new ReverseRegistrar();

// Register ReverseRegistrar as owner of ADDR_REVERSE_NODE
ENSRegistry ensRegistry = ENSRegistry(/* address of your deployed ENSRegistry */);
bytes32 reverseNode = /* compute the reverse node */;
address reverseRegistrarAddress = address(reverseRegistrar);

// Ensure that the calling address is authorized to set the owner
require(ensRegistry.owner(ADDR_REVERSE_NODE) == msg.sender || ensRegistry.operators[ensRegistry.owner(ADDR_REVERSE_NODE)][msg.sender]);

// Register the ReverseRegistrar as the owner of ADDR_REVERSE_NODE
ensRegistry.setOwner(reverseNode, reverseRegistrarAddress);
```

3. **Deploy NameWrapper:**
   Now, when you deploy the `NameWrapper` contract, it should recognize the `ReverseRegistrar` as the owner of the reverse node, and the constructor logic should work without issues.

This approach ensures that the reverse registrar is registered as the owner of the reverse node before the `ReverseClaimer` constructor is called.

Please replace the placeholder comments with the actual addresses and values needed in your deployment. Additionally, verify and test thoroughly before deploying any contracts to the mainnet.

Comment: ENSRegistry is deployed and the owner of reverseNode is address(0).
To change the owner of reverseNode as you said, the existing owner needs to call setOwner(), or setApprovalForAll(), and the existing owner is address(0).

Comment: If the `ENSRegistry` is deployed, and the owner of the reverse node (`ADDR_REVERSE_NODE`) is `address(0)`, it poses a challenge for changing the owner because setting the owner requires authorization from the current owner. If the current owner is `address(0)`, there is no entity to provide authorization.

In Ethereum's ENS system, the reverse node (`ADDR_REVERSE_NODE`) is typically owned by the account to which the address belongs. However, if the reverse node is initially owned by `address(0)`, it may complicate the ownership transfer process.

Comment: 1. **Ownership during Deployment:**
   - Ensure that the reverse node is initially owned by the correct address during the deployment of the `ENSRegistry` contract.

2. **Proxy or Administrative Account:**
   - Use a proxy contract or an administrative account to handle the initial registration of the reverse node and subsequent ownership changes.

3. **ENS Registry Migration:**
   - If feasible, you might consider migrating to a new instance of the ENS registry where the reverse node ownership is properly configured during deployment.

Comment: 4. **Collaboration with ENS Operators:**
   - If the ENS registry is part of a larger ENS system, consider collaborating with ENS operators or administrators who may have special privileges to manage reverse nodes.

5. **ENS Governance Proposals:**
   - If the ENS registry has a governance mechanism, you could propose a governance action to update or correct the ownership of the reverse node.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with this, and the root cause of it is somehow the dependencies of the scripts inside the `deploy` folder doesn't work on my custom testnet (the dependency scripts doesn't run first), however, it works fine in local hardhat network.

To solve this issue, you need to manually call the functions of the contracts (using Remix IDE or any other method to interact with contracts using ABIs) to mimic the code of the deployment scripts.

The way I did was to run the scripts on my local hardhat network (by running `yarn test:deploy` command) then get the logs. Based on the logs, you would know which functions to call in which order. Once you have resolved the dependency issue, try running it on your testnet again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this is not what you suggested, but we have resolved the issue in a different way.
The ReverseRegistrar was registered with the namehash 'addr.reverse' by default, so by registering the reverse labe on the zero node via setSubnodeOwner() and then registering the addr label on the created reverse node, I was able to specify the owner of addr.reverse as intended.
I solved this by checking the 'Deploying ENS on a Private Chain' chapter in the official documentation of ENS.